# Travel from Amsterdam City Centre to Efteling Amusement park and other information

Tags: public-transport, amsterdam, amusement-parks

I will be staying in [Hotel Eden](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place?cid=11105840629229533852) in Amsterdam during 8th to 11th November. On 11th I want to go to the Efteling Amusement Park with my wife and my 3 year old son. As I could figure out, it will open at 11AM in the morning and being a Tuesday there should not be too much crowd. Google Maps suggests that if I go by Public Transport, it will take us around 2 hours to reach there whereas taking a taxi cab would take around 1 hour. I want to know the approximate fare the taxi cab would charge? Also, by what time should I leave the park to get back to Amsterdam? Will it be safe in the evening to travel such a long distance (more than 100km)?

Also, does Efteling have a concept of **Express Tickets**, i.e. the kind of ticket which allows you to jump the queue?

Comment: You mean the queue at the entrance or for each ride?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question about safety, what's your concern?

Comment: [They publish a calendar about expected attendance](http://www.efteling.com/NL/Openingstijden/Plan-je-bezoek-kalender.html) and the 11th is indeed a ‘calm’ day.

Comment: @Relaxed I mean the queue for each ride. About safety, in many parts of the world, travel is unsafe in the night due to crimes, thefts etc. That's my concern.

Comment: The 11th is Sint Maartenday/beginning of carnival season going through 's Hertogenbosch might cause delays

Comment: @andra So what time do you suggest we leave from Amsterdam to avoid those delays?

Comment: @dharm0us Oh, I see. The Netherlands is not like that, pickpockets are an issue (even during the day) but many people go out at night, eat out in the evening, etc. and I never felt unsafe in public transportation. Besides, the park closes at 6, you should be in Amsterdam by 8, it will be dark but not quite evening yet.

Comment: Would renting a car be an option?

Answer (score 2):

Taxi would be more than EUR 150-200 (one way) I think. [This website suggests it could be up to EUR 260](http://www.taxiprijsberekenen.nl/). Public transportations are good in the Netherlands but the park is out of town and 2 hours is long. Maybe taking a cab to the station on both ends (Amsterdam and 's-Hertogenbosch) and a train in-between could cut the time and be a good compromise. Renting a car could also make sense.

You can buy tickets for the Efteling online. I did it last year and did not have to wait at the entrance at all (but it's not like there was a long queue for regular tickets either). There are no express tickets to jump the queues for the rides as far as I know (the whole idea would seems at odd with the local culture and the atmosphere of the park in my opinion) but wait times for the rides are very reasonable (at least for the winter Efteling, summer might be a bit more crowded). There are special “luxury” tickets but they mostly offer lunch, souvenirs and entrance 30 min earlier, no special treatment in queues.

Don't expect Disneyland or Europa-Park, it's a completely different experience. They have started adding a few “thrill rides” to broaden their appeal (I highly recommend the “Villa Volta” madhouse but your kid is too young for that) but that's not the main focus. Signature attractions like the fairy tale forest don't even have queues at all, you just come along and wander around as you please.

About coming back late, in the winter it's getting dark early and it could be raining so I guess technically there is a somewhat higher risk of traffic accident but I don't see any reason to be concerned about safety.